# Excel: importing data from one table to the other based on conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

At first I'd like to say hello to everyone, as this is my first post here.

I’d like to ask for help regarding an excel formula importing data from one table to the other.

I have two Tables:

```
**Table 01**  
A      B  
01  
01.t  
02.th  
03.fth  

**Table 02**  
A    B  
t    terrace  
h    handed  
f    frosted
```

In Table 01, column A, I’d like to place information from Table 02 column B like in the example below:

```
A        B  
01  
01.t     terrace  
02.th    terrace, handed  
03.fth   frosted, terrace, handed
```

I can imagine that the formula is going to include If…Then and Vlookup, but I can’t figure it myself.
Thank you in advance.

**Update:**
I work in Excel 2013.

Comment: It will require TEXTJOIN() which is available in Office 365 Excel.  If you do not have that then it will require vba.

Comment: As stated the only way with Excel 2013 is vba.  You will need to loop through each character and use Application.Match or Find to find the letter in Table 2 and concatenating the return value.

Comment: Do you need all the data to be in column B? What if you have B for the first match (`terrace`), then C has `handed`, etc.?

Comment: @BruceWayne I need it in one cell, separated by commas.

Comment: Welcome to the site. How many different values to be looked up (like f,t & h) are there? And what is the max number of such values that a result would have?

Comment: @Bandersnatch Hi. There are 6 values max, and all of them are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula is a bit cumbersome, but this table shows the results using the formula shown at the bottom:

[image]

Here is the entire formula in B1:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>3,VLOOKUP(MID(A1,4,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")&IF(LEN(A1)>4,", "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,5,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")&IF(LEN(A1)>5,", "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,6,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")&IF(LEN(A1)>6,", "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,7,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")&IF(LEN(A1)>7,", "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,8,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")&IF(LEN(A1)>8,", "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,9,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")
```

and here it is again, broken up to show the pattern:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>3,     VLOOKUP(MID(A1,4,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")
&IF(LEN(A1)>4,", "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,5,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")
&IF(LEN(A1)>5,", "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,6,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")
&IF(LEN(A1)>6,", "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,7,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")
&IF(LEN(A1)>7,", "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,8,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")
&IF(LEN(A1)>8,", "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,9,1),D$1:E$6,2,FALSE),"")
```

This assumes that it's possible for a cell in Column A to have all six letters after the period.  If that's not possible, you can remove one or more sections of the formula.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and clarification. It works perfectly.